# MongoReplicaSetClient does not reconnect in celery workers

Tags: mongodb, celery, pymongo

I use Celery 3.0.15 with MongoDB 2.4.4 replica set as a backend (pymongo version 2.5.1). I also use the same replica set as a main application data storage:

```
CELERY_CONFIG = {
    'BROKER_URL': 'mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/',
    'BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS': {
        'replicaSet': 'test'
    }
}

...

conn = MongoReplicaSetClient(
    'localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019', 
    replicaSet='test'
)
```

I can start some workers and use this `conn` instance to access database from code inside celery tasks.

If mongo primary shuts down and gets re-elected, celery workers automatically reconnect to a new configuration. But all subsequent queries with `conn` return `AutoReconnect` exception no matter how many retries I make and no matter how long I wait.

Separating replica sets for broker and for main database does not solve the problem: workers still reconnect normally, but I cannot access mongo from tasks using the same MongoReplicaSetClient.

**UPDATE**

Manually calling `conn.refresh()` after `AutoReconnect` solves the problem. Seems that `MonitorThread` is not working properly in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the way celery starts its workers. By default, in 3.0.15 it uses `fork()` which copies the state of parent process, but makes `MonitorThread` dead. The solution is to use `CELERYD_FORCE_EXECV` option which forces celery to run workers with `execv()` and makes monitor alive and happy again.